# Can triggers be chained with IFTTT?

Tags: ifttt, connector-services

When using IFTTT, it's trivial to connect one trigger (*if this*) to one event/output (*then that*). However, I'm interested in using IFTTT for a slightly more complex query, along the lines of *"if this happens 3 times, do that"*.

A [Quora question](https://www.quora.com/Can-you-use-two-or-more-triggers-and-actions-on-IFTTT-How-can-I-do-that/answer/Hans-Andersson-1) discusses this and suggests Numerous as a channel which can be used for more complex triggers, but it turns out that Numerous [had to shut down due to lack of funding](http://blog.numerousapp.com/2016/02/02/numerous-shutting-down-on-may-1.html) several months ago.

A similar question [was asked on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ifttt/comments/43wpwo/are_there_any_good_alternatives_to_numerous_for/) with no satisfying answer, so I'm asking here in the hope that there is a better solution to my problem: **How can I chain triggers in more complex queries with IFTTT?** Is this even possible now that Numerous has shut down, or will I have to use an alternative service?

Comment: Now without using your own arduino channel, I think (at least this seemed to be the case about 6 months ago)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update May 2019. [Stringify is shutting down](https://www.stringify.com/stringifyshuttingdown/).

I've only just discovered this platform, but https://www.stringify.com/ appears to support both logic processing, 
[image: Stringify Action & Condition visualization including two logical ANDs]
and [sequential actions](https://search.stringify.com/flows/NL8Me0MZX7qCrmlamNgn) in it's flows. It can interact with IFTTT.

Comment: This seems like an ideal solution; thanks for spotting it. I'll give it a try to check how well it works when I get chance, but if it's as good as it looks, it should be pretty useful.

Comment: @Aurora0001 I saw on the forum, a limit of 10 variables per 'user'. Its pretty new, so that might change.

Comment: Stringify engineer here! We now offer up to 20 variables including having an action to increment a variable and a trigger for "if a variable changes" and "if a variable is less than X". Happy to answer any other questions on the platform you have.

Answer (score 9):

In fact you are searching for a IFTTT equivalent with internal variables and eventually fork actions to store a counter for example...

- [Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/) handles all that but runs only on phones and has only phone events (it can do http call though)
- [Netvibes](http://www.netvibes.com/) manages multiple triggers and actions, but if you want vars you must perform a GET/POST with information through the HTTP call feature

Comment: Thanks Goufalite. Is there no way of doing this with IFTTT itself that you know then?

Answer (score 6):

[Zapier](http://www.zapier.com) is another tool you can use if you are not aware:

> Zapier moves info between your web apps automatically, so you can focus on your most important work.

There is a [list of integrations here](https://zapier.com/zapbook/)—most are related to web applications rather than IoT devices, although you can integrate with AWS Lambda (or similar services) which might be useful in an IoT environment.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please note that good answers should preferably include some details (i.e. how is this tool used in a certain way specific to the question) and not just a link.

Comment: Does this tool actually solve the posed question? It doesn't show any IoT activities on the front page that I found....

Answer (score 3):

IFTTT have now launched a [maker platform](https://ifttt.com/blog/2017/05/calling-all-makers) which appears to support filters and chaining. I've not yet worked out if it has timers and cloud side variables/storage.